# Retrieve data from the json file in JavaScript and display flower and color in different ul

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

Retrieve data from the json file in JavaScript and display flower and color in different ul,
i am try to add but trouble here how can i make it,

```
fetch('dataFiles/midterm.json', { 
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors'
    })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
        //console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        //data =  response.text();
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);

        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML += "<ul></ul>";
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML += "<ul></ul>";
    // Process data
    })
    .catch ( (err) => { // Process Error
     });


// json here
{ "inventory": [ 
        {"type": "flower",
         "cars": [
            { "make" : "VW","model" : "Bug","cost" : 24000 },
            { "make" : "GMC","model" : "Suburban","cost" : 18000 }]}, 
        {"type": "color",
         "cars": [
            { "make" : "VW","model" : "Jetta","cost" : 25000 },
            { "make" : "Chevy","model" : "Tahoe","cost" : 30000 },
            { "make" : "FORD","model" : "F150","cost" : 29000 },    
            { "make" : "HYUNDAI","model" : "Elantra","cost" : 27500 }]}
            ] 
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**Create and add list items**

The problem with your code is that `<ul>` are added, but without any list items `<li>`. There is nothing to display.

To fix the problem, build an html string from the fetched data. You can do this using an outer and inner [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to display the child array "cars" within each inventory type, i.e., flowers and colors.

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to build the html and then display the complete list in the data element as shown.

**Snippet**

Review and run the snippet to understand how it works.

```js
let data ={"inventory":[{"type":"flower","cars":[{"make":"VW","model":"Bug","cost":24000},{"make":"GMC","model":"Suburban","cost":18000}]},{"type":"color","cars":[{"make":"VW","model":"Jetta","cost":25000},{"make":"Chevy","model":"Tahoe","cost":30000},{"make":"FORD","model":"F150","cost":29000},{"make":"HYUNDAI","model":"Elantra","cost":27500}]}]};


// inside fetch.then(

let html = "";

data.inventory.forEach(item => {
  html += `<h4>${item.type}</h4><ul>`;
  item.cars.forEach(car => {
     html += `<li>${car.make}, ${car.model}, ${car.cost}</li>`;
  });
  html += "</ul>";
});

document.querySelector("#data").innerHTML = html;
```

```css
h4 {
  background-color: steelblue;
  color:white;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```